# Cascade update child when update parent

Tags: java, rest

I'm working on creating web application. 
In the project I have 3 entities:

- Suit
- Case
- Step

One Suit contains many Cases and one Case contains many Steps. All information represent only on one web page. So on the web page we have information about one Suit, list of Cases that includes into this Suit, and all Steps for each Case.
On the web page we also have one button for save all information about Suit. So, customer can change everything that he wants. He can delete and insert steps or cases, but all changes will be save when he clicks on the "Save" button.
So my question is: **"How correctly write a query to update all the information?"**

**Small example:** We get on the backend something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Suit name",
    "cases":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Case 1",
            "steps":[
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Case 1 first step"
                } 
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Case 2",
            "steps":[
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Case 2 first step"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Case 2 second step"
                } 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When customer update suit information, for example he can add a new step into "Case 1", and delete "Case 2". In this situation, I create a new JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "New suit name",
    "cases":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Case 1",
            "steps":[
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Case 1 first step"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Case 1 second step"
                } 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I get this JSON object, it's really hard to detect what was changed (update, delete or add), so I delete all information about suit and insert again.

Another problem that this JSON-object sends:

```
PUT http://example.com/suit/1
```

I can use it REST API for add, update and delete all elements in suit, if I correctly specify JSON-object.

But I think it's wrong way. The REST API PUT must only update the information about the elements or add elements if they did not exist, but not delete.

May be someone faced with a similar problem. I'll be glad to listen to your comments and suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In restfull API I would suggest to query via API if the object exist and call accordingly, in example if exist call update if doesn't call create.

You will not have to deal with all of this mess on a server side